# Promise: pass a value in serialization of asynchronous code seems doesn't work properly in my code

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

I'm learning Promise.  I wrote this simple code to practice the theoretical concepts learned. But it doesn't behave as expected. In my understanding the `Promise.resolve` is in a resolve state, thereby the `then()` is  executed immediately and the object is passed as `value`. The handler of the `then()` return a `Promise` because i want to seralize  the asynchronous code. In the Promise the synchronous code is execuded instead the `setTimeout` should be put in the Job Queue. Then, the synchronous execution code continue but the following `then` doesn't exec because the calling `Promise` is in a `pending` state. Thus only when the callback of the `setTimeout` run the Promise become in `resolve` state and in the meanwhile pass the value Object. I would expect that the second console.log in the second `then()` method to perform after 5 seconds but it isn't the case. The three `console.log` print immediately.

```js
 Promise.resolve({id:"1",type:"person"})
      .then((value) => new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
         console.log(value);
         value.id="2";
         setTimeout(resolve(value),5000);
         }
      ))
      .then((value) => new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
         console.log(value);
         value.id="3";
         setTimeout(resolve(value),5000);
         }
      ))
      .then((value)=>console.log(value));
```

This code works, but without to pass the object between the Promises:

```js
 Promise.resolve({id:"1",type:"person"})
      .then((value) => new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
         console.log("1");
         value.id="2";
         setTimeout(resolve,5000);
         }
      ))
      .then(() => new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
         console.log("2");
         
         setTimeout(resolve,5000);
         }
      ))
      .then(()=>console.log("3"));
```

Where am I wrong? 
Which puzzle piece am I missing?

Comment: you're not passing a function to settimeout in the first code ... your calling resolve immediately, and passing the result of calling resolve to settimeout (which is undefined so the setimeout doesn't receive a function callback) ... try `setTimeout(resolve, 5000, value)`

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, you are right. Here is late, better to go to sleep.  However the parameters of the setTimeout should be valued immediately and the resolve(value) function call cause that setTimeout isn't executed.

Comment: erm, no, that didn't make sense - what I suggested is the same as `setTimeout(() => resolve(value),5000);` if that helps

Comment: I understood your workaround. In the previous comment I was trying to explain the behavior of my first code with bug.

Comment: oh, I explained that in my first comment too :p

Comment: Yes you are right again. resolve(value) cause Promise become in a resolve state, and resolve(value) return undefined as value. But the setTimeout is still executed, the callback is still put in the Job Queue but the callback is undefined thus it does nothing once elapsed 5 seconds. Thanks now everything it's clear.